# how to access pivot table column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have bican roles plugin and I need to access over pivot table. This is in my controller code

```
   $users = User::where('role_id','=',2)->get();
```

migration roles

```
   Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->integer('level')->default(1);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

migration user

```
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

pivot migration

```
   Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relation between user and role is many-to-many then it looks that you are querying `User` incorrectly. The right query will be as:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($q) {
                    $q->where('role_id', 2);
              })
              ->get();
```

Then you can get user's role as:

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->roles; // returns collection of roles
}
```

Comment: one question, whereHas looks at a pivot table?

Comment: `whereHas` is used for querying relationship. You can read the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).